# sh file only executes all commands but only the last command works

Tags: node.js, sh

Please help me, I am trying to get a auto restart on my program using a .sh file. My code:
`node ./server.js
node ./server.js`
but i keep getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCqzc.png)

please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message

```
'rror: Cannot find module '/root/Clones/server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    ...
```

It looks like it's trying to load `server.js^M`, where `^M` represents a Ctrl-M or Carriage Return character (also known as `\r` or `\015` or `\x0D`).

Is your shell script in windows format, with CR/LF line endings? You have to convert it to unix format (just LF (line feed)).